# what is eMode in visual basic 6.0? How is it linked to recordsets?

Tags: vb6, recordset

I have a Dim statement that declares "vMode as eMode". It is used to change the status of recordset mode like read,write and cancel. I want to full capabilities of eMode object and how it is related to recordset object.Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely it is an Enumeration of modes declared somewhere else in your code. I don't think anyone here can answer this without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a guess as there is no `eMode` type that I know of but I'd suggest that it's a (re)definition of `EditModeEnum` which is the type of the `Recordset.EditMode` property, described here [EditMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/editmode-property?view=sql-server-2017).